# ios7 all searchviews and tableviews off by 20 pixels

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

EDIT:  This is not an issue with the frame. The frame is in the correct spot. It is the content that is off. Yes, we are compensating for clear status bar. ViewDidLoad shows content offset is at 0,0.

On every page of my applcation that has a scrollview it's content is pushed down by 20 pixels. I think it may have something to do with the new StatusBar, or lack thereof. The bug also seems to be present in the simulators settings menu. Screenshot below. This only seems to affect the first scroll view that is added to a ViewController and only if no other views have been added to it. Table views are also being affected because they inherit from Scroll view. To be clear the scrollview starts at the correct origin but the content is pushed down by 20 pixels. This is bizarre because I would think if it was a status bar issue it would be 20 pixels above not below.

Currently we are fixing it by adding this to our base view controller

```
UIView *hackView = [[UIView alloc] init];
hackView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
[self.view addSubview:hackView];
```

Obviously, this is a hack.

The same thing is happening on phone and in simulator even with the Gold Member version of IOS7 when building for latest IOS7. You can even see an example of the bug in the simulator's settings tableview and also in ours below.

[image]

[image: IOS7 settings]

This is a screenshot immediately after it loads. One bizarre thing that we noticed is that when we execute a pull to refresh it will correct the scrollview and rest at it's correct location. Alternatively, if we compensate it will look correct in the beginning but any subsequent pull to refreshes will migrate the scrollview to -20px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you laying out your views? With autolayout you can use the `topLayoutGuide`, which should accommodate for these offsets.

Comment: Everything is in code and we are calculating everything by hand. We have not yet switched to AutoLayout yet. Will auto layout affect the content as well? From my understanding (I could be wrong) that is just going to affect the frame of the container not necessarily the content.

Comment: I don't know - I had similar issues that I resolved by using auto layout with the `topLayoutGuide`. Sorry.

Comment: No need to be sorry. I was just expressing my concern. I am going to need to implement auto layout anyway at the moment I am trying to avoid it because it is a big code overhaul. (All our Views are made in code and we have bigger issues) if that is the solution I will be sure to give you credit.

Comment: Yeah, there are usually more important things - but the autolayout transition is very rewarding. In Xcode 5's Storyboards, the constraints are finally useful (Xcode is not trying to be too smart with putting in constraints you don't want) - only what you add is actually there. In case you wanted to use code, I am actually writing a little Autolayout-shortcut methods that I am planning on putting on github (will post link here when I do). But `NSLayoutConstraint`s themselves are pretty easy to handle (but I was lazy, so I wrote the lib).

Comment: How do you access the toplayoutguide in the interface builder/storyboard?

Comment: In Xcode 5, it should be an element in the view hierarchy in the Storyboard. https://www.dropbox.com/s/7fjdc8liffkywpi/Screenshot%202013-09-19%2010.17.46.png

Comment: @czechboy Did you write those autolayout-shortcut methods you mentioned?

Comment: I did, but I haven't gotten to put them up yet. I'll do it tomorrow and put the link here. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: cool thanks! @SeanDunford, I'm a little confused how you solved this problem. from the looks of things, you transitioned to use auto-layout for everything..? I also have everything coded by hand and find myself in the same exact situation you were/are in. making this big of a transition really kills me and I've been looking for an interim solution. the last hurdle I need to face is why the search results tableview is coming down 20px. any help is very, very appreciated

Comment: I didn't. I kept the hack of the extra view and I moved on with my life. We have too many other issues to push for auto layout everything. Maybe after the ios7 hype we will try it. I tried submitting a radar but I got a bug crash on that as well. I emailed them and they haven't responded.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, but here it is, the shortcuts to creating autolayout constraints in code: https://github.com/czechboy0/DUIToolbox#constraint-factory

Hope you find it useful, let me know if you want any more use cases there.

Answer (score 3):

After further testing in Xcode, my original workaround still works, but the real culprit seems to be a Navigation Controller combined with the Adjust Scroll View Insets flag on the view controller. Disabling that solved the issue.

```
[self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO];
```

---

Original workaround: Try reordering your view hierarchy or add an empty view at the top.

This happened to me, and it appears that when a UIScrollView or similar subclass is first in the hierarchy it gets offset by 20 pixels (to keep it from hitting the status bar). However, this still occurs even when the view in question is nowhere near the top.

This is reproducible in Interface Builder, and an easy workaround for me has been to reorder my views so that a label or button is first under the view controller's view. If that's not possible in your case, adding an empty view (even off screen) above your scrollview also seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Good answer but try to add a few lines of code to demonstrate your approach. It's always appreciated

Comment: setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets is also available in interface builder.

Answer (score 3):

I added this to my UIViewControllers in `viewDidLoad:` which were affected and it fixed the issue for me:

```
NSComparisonResult order = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion compare: @"7.0" options: NSNumericSearch];
if (order == NSOrderedSame || order == NSOrderedDescending)
{
    // OS version >= 7.0
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Another, cleaner method:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Comment: Will try this when I get in the office tomorrow. If it solves my issue I will let you know. Thanks for the response! Did you see any negative effects to adding it to views that weren't affected? I have a base class of View that i use. I am thinking of just adding it there to apply the fix to all my views whether or not they had the issue.

Comment: I added this to my tab UIViewControllers, as well as a few modal UIViewControllers and I have not seen any negative effects at all.

Answer (score 0):

In the Ios 7 the view starts from the window from y= 0, move your view to 20 pixel dowm

```
self.view.frame = CGRectmake (0,20,320,hight);
```

this is due to transparent status bar in iOS 7.

pull down the view to show it properly.

Comment: This is not the issue. We are compensating for this. The frame is in the correct spot. it is the content in the scroll view that is not.